# How to get a resource from string in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

Can you get a resource from a string like this in Kotlin?

```
val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
val diceRoll = (1..6).random()
diceImage.setImageResource("R.drawable.dice_${i}")
```

Comment: I want to remind you that Kotlin questions can sometimes be duplicates of Java questions, if the answer is one to one translatable (like in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`getIdentifier`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method:

```
val id  = resources.getIdentifier("resourceName", "drawable", packageName)
imageView.setImageResource(id)
```